# Rails render partial with modal and local variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render a partial in a popup (ideally a modal that I have to figure out) upon clicking on a "group name" that's not based on any database object, but rather based on local variables derived from an API. I've seen this older post: [Rendering partial in rails modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402700/rendering-partial-in-rails-modal), but it's simply not working for me. When I click, I merely am routed to root. I'm currently trying to do this by using display:none on a "render partial" and a .show() function when clicking on the "group name".

I'm newish to Rails and really struggling to learn Javascript, so I don't know what's going wrong.

Here's the view:

```
<div id="groups_show" style="display:none">
  <%= render partial: 'groups/group_full', :locals => {group: group} %>
</div>
<%= link_to group.name, root_url, class: "groups_showme" %>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.groups_showme').click(function() {
  $('#groups_show').show();
  win = new Window({title: "Share This", width:200, height:150, destroyOnClose: true,     
  recenterAuto:false});
  win.setContent('#groups_show',true,true);
  win.show();
}
```

**EDITS: FINAL CODE THAT WORKED**

```
$('.groups_showme').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#groups_show').show();
 win = new Window({title: "Share This", width:200, height:150, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:false});
 win.setContent('#groups_show',true,true);
 win.show();
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors in your JS code related to this behavior:

1. `click(function()` should have an argument `e`
2. `e.preventDefault()` should be put at the first. For the last position, the equivalent is `return false`
3. [optional] better to use `on` instead of `click`

So,

```
$('.groups_showme').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // others
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm marking as correct. Though for some reason, the render is still appearing in page and not as a pop-up. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @MatthewMelone, it seems the code now works as per your last edition? By the way, only one method is needed for stopping link, either preventDefault or `return false`

Comment: Ah, thanks. If I'm understanding correctly, the whole win.setContent is from prototype, and I'm on jQuery. So now I'm trying to modify for jQuery and ending up with this mess. 

`$('.groups_showme').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#groups_show').show();
      var htmlString = $( this ).html();
      var dialog_form = $('<div id="dialog-form">Loading<div id="groups_show"></div></div>').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 520,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        return $(this).text( htmlString );
      },
      close: function() {....`